# Valence pagination of get requests

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I've got several questions about pagination.

1. Can pagination be forced?
2. Can pagination be controlled (eg request pages of 200 records)?
3. If answers to 1 & 2 are no, what is a threshold when pagination happens?
4. Is pagination stable (same number of records on the same entity will always either be paginated or not paginated)?

Thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score 3):

1. Pagination is forced when it gets used on a particular API call: no matter how many records it finds, that call will alway returns the data in pages. You cannot request pagination on calls that do not by default paginate. A call either paginates or it does not.
2. You cannot currently request a change to the size of data pages; the number of records returned in each page in a paged set is fixed for each call using pages (in *theory* the page size can vary with each such call, in practice, it (currently) does not).
3. There is no threshold: either the data in a call is returned in a paged result set, or it is not. If the number of matching results is less than the page size, the call should still return a single data page within a paged result set structure, with a property set to indicate no further data pages are available.
4. Yes, it is stable: you can rely that a call with paged results will always return paged results, and that the number of results returned in a page will remain static (as long as the product version for your service does not change: product upgrades *may* alter the size of data pages in paged results).

You should not write code that cannot cope with a change in the page size or that needs to know what the page size is (because that can change with a new product version *without a change to the API contract version*), but it is safe to write code that assumes that the returns from API call *A* will always be paged (if the docs say that it returns paged results).

Comment: Viktor,

Thanks a lot for the prompt reply.
It looks like I haven't expressed myself correctly.
My question were not about "paginated format", but about situations with real multiple pages.
One more clarification: most of them relates to test cases; production code is 100% dynamic.
So, I rephrase my questions:
1. Can pagination be forced (requested)?
2. I’m happy with your answer to this question.
3. What is a threshold when reply is split in more than 1 page?
   My tests shoe that “users/” are split after 100 records. Others?
4. I’m happy with your answer to this question

Comment: Viktor, thanks again, but you still haven't answered my follow on questions. I want to know 2 things: 1. What is the page size for each request (no, I will not use it in my production code). 2. Can this page size be varied in any way (configuration, request parameter, etc).

Comment: (1) The default page size is an implementation detail, and may vary, so there's no such thing as a "fixed number" for it. (2) No, the page size cannot be varied by the client, nor currently by the LMS admin: it's fixed/determined in the LMS code itself.